# Using javascript to check if a querystring has a value

Tags: javascript, query-string

New in JS, How do I check if one of my querystring has a value?

Example: I have result.aspx?loc=3. How do I check this in javascript if my querystring loc has a value. I need to do this because I will use $('#target').css({'display':'none'});  to a certain div

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try `location.search`

> The search property returns the query
>   portion of a URL, including the
>   question mark (?).

and can be called like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.write(location.search);
</script>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_search.asp